# Como criar certificado para servidor no SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, autenticação

Estou criando um aplicativo que utiliza o `SQL Server` como gerenciador do DB.

Meu problema está em fazer uma conexão segura entre o `DB` e o aplicativo, por isso preciso criar um certificado no servidor dentro do `SQL` para poder usar como identificador e possibilitar que os usuários façam o logon de forma segura.